# Как забиндить 2 Pivot Header разными значениями?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

[image: Pivot code]

Есть Pivot с двумя айтемами. Я засунул в HeaderTemplate два текстБлока. Первый текстБлок биндится просто добавлением свойства Header в PivotItem, а второй по количеству элементов в ListView, которых тоже 2.

Как мне забиндить так, чтобы второй текстБлок второго PivotItem биндился ко второму ListView, а не к первому, как я указал в коде?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил в `<PivotItem> <PivotItem.Header>`, и всё заработало.